# How to add an UISwitch to a grouped table view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What is the easiest way of creating an UISwitch inside a grouped table view without using a Settings Bundle? Is it possible to do it using Interface Builder without programmatically adding the switch? The desired appearance is like [this apple example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/art/ui_switchcontrolexample.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial to do what you want: http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/07/cells-with-switch/